# SQL Server Query to match multiple memberid

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to select only those members whose status is Alumni using a select query. All usMemID are comma separated, so if one of the usMemIDs usStatus='Alumni' it should show only that record.

I tried this but it is not displaying the expected results

```
Select * FROM tblUsers where usStatus='Alumni' and usMemID='J109617,J100392'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you be more specific about the memId, is that a plain nvharchar text, or is the result from another table?

If that's the case you can do

```
select * from tblusers 
where usstatus='Alumni' 
  and usMemid in (select memid from originTable)
```

If that isn't the case you need to assign the query to a variable

```
declare @query nvarchar(max)
set @query='select * from tblusers where ustatus=''alumni'' and usmemid in (''J109617'',''J100392'',...)

execute (@query)
```